# Kali Linux - Unmet dependecies

Tags: kali-linux

This is the code below. I tried doing

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

and nothing is working for me.

```
apt-get install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-6-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.24-10) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-glvnd-nvidia-glx : Conflicts: libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 but 375.39-1 is to be installed
 libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-glcore:i386 (= 375.39-1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

edit: I have tried removing all the packages and purging them but to no avail nothing works. Been researching fixes to this but I couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cure all for new users who are having issues with apt.

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends "package name"
```

This is the answer for our (my) problem. Personally I got rid of all packages that were giving me problems and I reinstalled program.

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends "gcc-multilib"
```